# How to extract specific content from a column of a dataframe and make new column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to make a new column containing the titles (for eg: Mr, Miss, Capt etc.) of the names given in the 'Name' column below.

```
train_df['Name'].head()

0                              Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
1    Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...
2                               Heikkinen, Miss. Laina
3         Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)
4                             Allen, Mr. William Henry
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Can you explain the above task also using `'pandas.Series.str.extract'`? Thank you.

Comment: Create a list of your titles, `'|'.join` them, use `str.extract` on the series

Comment: Can you please show me?, given the titles are Mr, Miss, Dr. Thank you.

Comment: And what if there are a number of titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.extract`:

```
df['Titles'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r', (\w+\.)')
```

Returns:

```
                                           Name Titles
0                       Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    Mr.
1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs)   Mrs.
2                        Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  Miss.
3  Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)   Mrs.
4                      Allen, Mr. William Henry    Mr.
```

You can see the regex in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/o3K3fU/1).

Comment: Yes. Please explain me the parameter in 'extract'( to be specific this part (r', (\w+\.)'). Thank you.

Comment: I've added a link to an online regex tester with the expression. A very thorough explanation is provided there. Hope that helps!